Statistics Problem related to two string match
I have two columns which has results of string match percentage now have to compare Model 1 and Model 2 that which model is more accurate
Model 1
10
20
30
50
65
32
Model2
0
12
15
40
32
43
Have to compare which model is more accurate regardless what was the model
Approach to solve this problem.I have to get the concept I can use to how to go with the problem.I tried getting rmse byt did get a proper solution

What do you mean by "proper solution"?  RMSE would point to model 1, which is obviously better overall, even though it falls slightly short in one of the six cases.
